# What is __return__?

Tags: python

I am debugging a script in Python 3.1 and discovered this:

> (Pdb) p locals()
>   {'count': 264, 'self': , 'depth': 1, 'offset': 0, **'__return__': None,** 'blkno': 4, 'size': 264}

I found [deferred PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0316/) that mentions it, and little else.

**What is `__return__`?** When was it added? How is it useful?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a **return value** of a function call when the **pdb debugger** stops after evaluating the return command. Is is very important for a return expressions with any side effect (that can't be reproduced like e.g. reading a line from pipe).

```
(Pdb) ...                       # stop somewhere in the debugger ...
> test.py(3)f()
-> return x + 1
(Pdb) l                         # list source: I'm just before return
1      def f():
2        x = 7
3  ->    return x + 1
(Pdb) '__return__' in locals()  # __return__ is still undefined
False
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> test.py(3)f()->8              # This printed 8 is a simple case, but frequently
(Pdb) '__return__' in locals()  # the value is an object or line shortened to 80 ch.
True                            # __return__ has the value after return
(Pdb) __return__
8
```

If the function exits without executing *return* command then is `__return__ == None` everytimes.

Answer (score 10):

The `__return__` keyword only appears in the debugger code:

```
matt@stanley:~/src/Python-3.2$ grep -R __return__ .
./Lib/pdb.py:        frame.f_locals['__return__'] = return_value
./Lib/pdb.py:        if '__return__' in self.curframe_locals:
./Lib/pdb.py:            self.message(repr(self.curframe_locals['__return__']))
./Lib/bdb.py:        if '__return__' in frame.f_locals:
./Lib/bdb.py:            rv = frame.f_locals['__return__']
```

Comment: Nice! Good way to really understand it in action.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common or garden local name, possibly a name for a function or a value, as you can tell from the fact that its name is in `locals()`. You would need to look at the code that defines it to see what it's used for. The fact that it starts with a double-underscore hints that it is a special value of some sort; perhaps it's used to hold the return value for some function. However, Python itself does not give any special meaning to the name `__return__`, so it could really be anything.

Knowing where you found it would be a nice start...