# How do you see the return value from a function in the Python debugger, without an intermediate?

Tags: python, debugging

PDB (and other Python debuggers) have a simple way of viewing the value of any current variable, just by typing it in. However, sometimes I work with libraries that don't store their return values in intermediate variables.

Here's an example function:

```
def do_stuff(*args, **kwds):
     return f(*args, **kwds)
```

After I return from f, how do I see the return value? I could rewrite libraries after I download them to have an intermediate:

```
def do_stuff(*args, **kwds):
     r = f(*args, **kwds)
     return r
```

but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: As it stands, the return value of `f` will also be the return value of `do_stuff`.  You could either look at that, or change it to something like `r = f(...); print(r); return r` -- I feel like your question is more complex than that, however.  Could you clarify?

Comment: That's actually the main question; is there a way to look at that value without an intermediate?

Comment: To have this feature in PyCharm please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13540

Comment: This has just been fixed in PyCharm, and should be available in the next release (2016.2).

Comment: I have PyCharm 2016.2, but it's not obvious how to see the return value and I don't see it in the documentation either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can look into a hidden **`__return__`** local variable.

If I would forget it's exact name, I explore it by this:

```
(Pdb) sorted(locals().keys())
['__return__', 'xyz', ...]
```

**EDIT**: Related later answer with [example of debugging with **`__return__`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18674516/448474)

Comment: Cool, thanks! Will have to see if that works in Eclipse, but I think it uses PDB by default...

Comment: I found also a pdb command `retval`, but I think "__return__" is more universal and more useful if the return value is a complicated object that can't be printed in detail.

Answer (score 7):

In pdb, when the function returns a `->'value'` is added at the end of the line with the representation of the returned value.

For example:

```
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> test.py(12)do_stuff()->'f'
-> return result
(Pdb) q
```

means `do_stuff()` returned `'f'`

Comment: If I understand this right, a step just before the return will show the return value, right? Does this work in Eclipse's implementation?

Comment: No, it actually happens when the function returns. I'm not sure about the Eclipse implementation, It should if use pdb (the debugger found in the standard library)

Comment: This is not always helpful, particularly when the return value is long or an object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more?

- By debugger, do you mean you are using a logger? Are you stepping through with an IDE?
- What do you mean by "see the return value"? If you just want to print it...

  ```
  def do_stuff(*args, **kwds):
      result = f(*args, **kwds)
      print result
      return result
  ```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and that sort of intermediate code is what I'd like to avoid using if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that VS Code has a feature called "[inline breakpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_inline-breakpoints)".

However, seems it currently does not work for python. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1101#issuecomment-1880463285) comment.