# Python - Doesn't return false

Tags: debugging

I am having trouble debugging this, I have a function, that picks up a few variables from previous functions, too many to be posted here, I guess, but they all work as intended and passed through the project automatic mooshak tests, however on this particular block of one function I can't get it to return false.

It prints the ('a') if the arguments I give it on the "debugger" meet the given conditions but it doesn't return. Any ideia of what could be causing this?

Edit: This is my entire function.

```
    def ask_play(t):
        # Creates a string to be used on the input msg that follows the projet rulles, (coordenada_linha(etc...)) are the used to calculate the maximum dimensions of the board.

        dim = str('(') + str((coordenada_linha(tabuleiro_dimensoes(t)))) + str(' : ') + str((coordenada_coluna(tabuleiro_dimensoes(t)))) + str(')')

        # Creates the input message.
        msg = 'Introduza uma jogada\n - coordenada entre (1 : 1) e ' + str(dim) +' >> '

        # xy picks the inputed (x : y) from the input and turns into (x ,y) so we can compare them to the maximum and minimum accepted coordenates.
        xy = eval((input(msg)).replace(' : ' , ', '))

        # Valor is just the number the coordenate should recieve.
        valor = int(input(' - valor >> '))

        # maxdim is the "highest coordenate on the board" in this case it's (5, 5)    
        maxdim = (((coordenada_linha(tabuleiro_dimensoes(t)))), ((coordenada_coluna(tabuleiro_dimensoes(t)))))

        # checks if the first input is a coordenate that is "inside" the grid, if it isn't, SHOULD return false, else it returns coordenate + given value
        if not ((((xy) >= (1, 1)) and ((xy) <= (maxdim)))):
            return False
        else:
            return cria_jogada(cria_coordenada(coordenada_linha(xy), coordenada_coluna(xy)), valor)
```

Best regards

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902203/how-do-you-see-the-return-value-from-a-function-in-the-python-debugger-without

Comment: What does it do instead of returning?

Comment: Instead of returning it just prints the A, if the conditions are OK it returns what it is supposed to return a tuple of coordinates followed by the value on that position. But when the conditions are not ok, which is what I use this condition for, it just prints (a) and I would like it to say False, not using print.

Comment: The function must return *something* though, right? What  's the output from running 'print ask_play(something)' where it goes through the troublesome route? Is it None?

Comment: According to the project papper the return should be.

If coordenate isn't available inside the grid - return: False

If the coordenate is available inside the grid - returns (x : y) --> value

If the first input (coordenate) is a string that can't be transformed into a coordenate the function has "no behavior"

The input argument that ask_play recieves is a function called board, that in turn recieves information from a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

check your text editor for mixed tabs and spaces? This [coding horror blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/death-to-the-space-infidels/) describes the issue I'm worried about.

My guess is the lines read like

```
if not ((((xy) >= (1, 1)) and ((xy) <= maxdim))):
....print('a')
> > return False
```

Or similar. Python counts tabs and spaces - your indenting level - to figure out what code goes in which conditional, or loop, or function. If you mix tabs and spaces, Python can get confused about what code belongs to what block. I suspect the return statement is suffering from this problem.

In notepad++, for example, you could choose the menu item

```
View->Show Symbol->Show White Space and Tab
```

to make it display tab characters and space characters. If some lines use tabs and some spaces, change them to be the same -- convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: I don't know how to do that? When I look at my WingIDE, notePAD++ or Notepad it doesn't show any wierd tabs, like the ones you gave in the example if thats what you mean by text editor.

Best regards

Comment: Everything appears to be ok on this front. I've done what you instructed, but everything looks just as if  I hadn't activated the "show white space and tab". I mean I can see some small pink dots but appart from that it appears everything is Ok. I've updated my main post with the whole function, however, I bet it's very confusing to read that wall of text.

Thanks for your help anyway.