# How to examine returned value of currently debugging function in PDB?

Tags: python, pdb

When examining a function in `pdb`, I can [run the `r(eturn)` command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands), which will continue to where the function returns.

How do I print (or otherwise examine) the value which will then be return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable `__return__` (no reference in the official doc, but you can find some details of the implementation in the source : [user_return](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pdb.py#L287) and [do_retval](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pdb.py#L1143))

```
def do_it():
    res = 'return me this'

    import pdb;
    pdb.set_trace()
    return res


then = do_it()


> debug_it.py(7)do_it()
-> return res
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> debug_it.py(7)do_it()->'return me this'
-> return res
(Pdb) __return__
'return me this'
```

(Another [S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073911/what-is-return) explains this variable)

Comment: I was *sure* it was possible but for the life of me couldn't find it in the docs! Thanks so much!

Comment: i found it with the command `locals()`, can be helpful too in this context ;)